# Views Orderering Not Correct

Tags: views

I need help with my Views. I have a field called 'Type'. There are eight types of resource. I have managed to get it to distinctly shows only one link to each type of resource by using aggregation. However, for some reason, it doesn't display the Types in the order they are listed in the field list for the content type ie. alphabetically). Anyone know why?

Here's the list as it appears currently in the View:

```
Conferences
Web Articles
Webinars
Blogs
Books
Certificate or Degrees
Tools
```

Here's the list I have set in the content type:

```
Blog|Blog
Book|Book
Certificate or Degree|Certificate or Degree
Conference|Conference
Newsletter|Newsletter
Tool|Tool
Web Article|Web Article
Webinar|Webinar
```

In the View I also have the following already set:

```
Sort Criteria: ASC, COUNT DISTINCT
Filter Criteria: COUNT(DISTINCT Content Type) (not empty) 
                 Content: Published (Yes)
```

Changing from ASC to DESC doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Have you checked the actual sql query? You can set views to show the sql query in the views settings at "admin/structure/views/settings"

Comment: Good tip. So, I did that and the following is what I got. Looks like it's ordering it by node.title for some reason...not sure how to change that or even why its doing that. I just want to sort by the items in the Type field list...which are of course connected to the node titles as a field. So basically its sorting the type list by the names of the resources that use the type, which makes no sense to me.

Comment: SELECT dfft.ftv AS fdft, MIN(node.nid) AS nid, 'node' AS field_data_field_type_node_entity_type, COUNT(DISTINCT node.title) AS node_title
FROM 
{node} node
LEFT JOIN {field_data_field_type} field_data_field_type ON node.nid = field_data_field_type.entity_id AND (field_data_field_type.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_type.deleted = '0')
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') ))
GROUP BY field_data_field_type_node_entity_type, field_data_field_type_field_type_value
HAVING (( (COUNT(DISTINCT field_data_field_type.field_type_value) IS NOT NULL) ))
ORDER BY node_title ASC

Comment: So you are sorting by node title. You can add a new sort in the bottom section on the left for your display. First add the new sort, then hit 'rearrange' to either delete the title sort or move your type sort above it.